# How to override or remove conditional formatting in Google Sheets by using Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-apps

**Long story short:** I need some help modifying script to override or remove conditional formatting colors applied in Google Sheets based on whether a cell has a note in it.

**Full explanation:** I have [this scheduling template](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1NlOirQkGUPyU4xeK-dzERNDxGvUfiQ7kAhMx6Op4r2s/edit?usp=sharing) that we're using to track a content production work. The editor likes having conditional formatting to show where the soonest dates are on the sheet. We'd also like to mark cells complete by adding a note to them (so we can see the planned completion date in the cell and the actual completion date in the note), which would then gray out that cell. Graying out cells with notes works with this script cobbled together from the forums:

```
function onOpen() {   var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet(),
   data = sheet.getDataRange(),
   notes = data.getNotes(),
   bkgs = data.getBackgrounds();   for (var i = 0, len = notes.length; i < len; i++)   {
 for (var j = 0, jlen = notes[0].length; j < jlen; j++)
 {
   if (notes[i][j])
     bkgs[i][j] = 'gray';
 }   }   data.setBackgrounds(bkgs); }
```

However, it won't gray out cells where conditional formatting exists, so I looked for more code to solve that issue. I tried adding sheet.clearFormats(); inside the if statement, like this:

```
{
   if (notes[i][j])
     bkgs[i][j] = 'gray';
     sheet.clearFormats();
 }   }   data.setBackgrounds(bkgs);
```

...which seemed to work at first, but then completely paralyzed the sheet. It then stalled the next couple of times I tried opening and closing it. Any ideas on how to override or remove the conditional formatting in this setting without crashing the tab?

Answer (score 0):

setBackground is a range object. It won't work with an array, this works:

```
function changeConditionalFormat() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
  var s = ss.getActiveSheet()
  var range= s.getRange(2,8,5,1)
  range.clearFormat()
  range.setBackground('grey');
}
```

Comment: Ah, good point! Is there a way to get this to work only on cells where a note has been added? I'm tinkering with it but keep getting errors in my code. (Sorry, I'm very much a beginner on this.)